# How do you break up a .module file?

Tags: 9

I have a .module file that is nearly 1000 lines long. I have functions that i want to reuse from form submission in a cron job.  What is the best way to abstract that to a better file?

Comment: This question is a little too broad. As a general answer I'd say move your helper functions into a service class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.module` file should contain only hook implementations. Other functions should be in classes as stateless static methods or as service object methods.

If the `.module` file contains only hook implementations and is still too big, use `require` statements to split up the file. Webform module uses this technique.